# Python - list assignment index out of range when trying to assign value to list item within loop

Tags: python, list

I am trying to assign (or replace) items within a list inside two nested for loops. Below is the code (base_list is already defined, so the code might look incomplete):

```
list_init = 'test'
# converting new list to type list
new_list = list(list_init)
flag = [0]
for i in range(len(base_list)):
    for j in range(i, len(base_list)):

        if base_list[i] == base_list[j]:
            print(base_list[j],' is equals to', base_list[i])
            # below is the error line
            new_list[j] = base_list[j]
            flag[j] = 1
        else:
            print(base_list[j],' is not equals to', base_list[i])
            # below is the error line
            new_list[j] = base_list[j]
            flag[j] = 0
```

What I am doing is to iterate over same list (base_list) twice to compare each element of the list with each other element after that element, and whenever a match is found, I am assigning the first base_list value to new_list for each match. When match is not found, I am assigning current base_list value as it is to  new list. Therefore I am taking second loop as:

```
for j in range(i, len(base_list))
```

This is to make sure that second loop starts from the list item active in first loop, and does not iterate from beginning.

Now the problem is in the following line:

```
new_list[j] = base_list[j]
```

I am getting the following error:

```
new_pl[j] = pl_list[i]
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

The same kind of problem I am facing with the flag list:

```
flag[j] = 1
```

Can you please suggest any solution to assign (or replace) list element values within loops using indices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with the way you are initializing `new_list`, in this line:

```
new_list = list(list_init)
```

Your `list_init` is set to `'test'`, so when you create `new_list`, it looks like

```
['t', 'e', 's', 't']
```

Then, if the length of `base_list` is > 4, you are trying to assign an element to `new_list` at index 5 for example, and getting an `IndexError`.

You should create `new_list` like so:

```
new_list = [None] * len(base_list)
```

This way you can ensure that `new_list` has the same length as `base_list` and you won't get any `IndexErrors`. Same thing for `flag`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but even if I remove the faulty initialization and do as you told, I am getting the same error. Is there any problem in loops or anything? I am a python beginner so no idea. :)

Comment: Now the error has become: "IndexError: list index out of range" when I am doing: new_list[j] = base_list[i]

Comment: Update: even if I am trying to print base_list value, like this: print(base_list[i]), after the if condition, it is giving list index out of range error.

Comment: I think it was my fault. Thanks a lot for the help. I will get back in case of any issues. Will mark green after testing. :)